EFI stub: WARNING: failed to measure data for event 1: 0xB000000009, may you provide a solution?
This message "EFI stub: WARNING: failed to measure data for event 1: 0xB000000009" is showing at the top left corner while I starting my laptop (Ubuntu 24.04 recently installed, Dell).
Any solution here? TIA

This question is similar to: EFI stub: WARNING: Failed to measure data for event 1: 0800000000000000b EFI stub. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
